# Moss all over soil in garden

Tags: soil, moss

Cannot get rid of moss in or on the soil in my garden so what plants can I grow in the moss.
Desperate to have a flower garden not a moss ridden garden!!??
Gill

Comment: We probably need more information to help you -  Location (I assume UK based on your user name and moss issue, but where in the UK? Or do you live somewhere like NZ or Australia?), amount of sun the area gets, soil type (ericaceous? calcareous? Clay? Loam? Sand?), length & width of garden, max height/width of plants you'd like to see in the garden, etc. A photo would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Moss is *generally* an indicator of acid soil and low light levels (lots of shading.) If you're not able to cut trees, or you are heavily shaded by things other than trees (as in a city location) you'll have to work with that. If you can remove things causing shade and get more light in, that can help immensely.

Referring to "flowers that are happy in my blueberry bed" (acid, but decent light) Daffodils, bleeding hearts, snowdrops and crocus all do fine, other than the squirrels raiding the crocus bulbs. Not sure any of those would flower much (other than the first season for the bulbs) in low-light conditions.